How to apply minus front in photoshop
Thousands of tutorials on YT about how to substract shape layers, one shape from another. but no one talks about how to substract one rasterize layer from another. I know nothing abot photoshop. :@ Please someone guide me how can I delete this circle from that red body. I am trying for last 40 minutes. I cant do it. I feel like am in pacific ocean without any life jacket and I dnt knw how to swim  
Please.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately it's not possible. Boolean operations such as Minus Front only work with vectors.  For raster image layers you'd need to use a layer mask, or make a selection and delete it. However, the latter is destructive. Layer masks are better as they're non destructive.

Hello, I am doomed. Layer masked dsnt work in animation. I cant animate it then. How can I select and delete it can u please tell me that> I treied, selected both (Ctrl click on  both layer) thn applied eraser to remove the circle part. but it dsnt go away from the red body. circle gets removed.  But I want to erase the overlapping part. I am so doomed.

You didn't mention animation in your original question.  Although Photoshop can be used for simple animations like GIFs, it's not technically animation software. It's a raster image editor, with very limited support for vector layers.  When things start to get more complex,  it might be better to have a look at Adobe Animate CC - which is software specifically designed for 2D animation.  Adobe Animate is vector based, but it can also animate raster elements.

Using Photoshop for animation is a bit like using a hammer to fix a screw, when what you really need is a screwdriver. While you can certainly hammer that screw in if you apply enough force, and it will work to a degree, it's essentially the wrong tool for the job.

In the meantime, if you really must use Photoshop, you could perhaps redraw the tractor body as a vector shape with the Pen Tool.  Then you can create a circle shape, then select both layers and do Layer > Combine Shapes > Subtract Front Shape.

NO No Billy!! not in  PS animation nor Adobe animate. Am gonna us it in Motion graphic, I will use it in After effects for a scene. AE dsnt support any  of those masking in animation. It has to be pure rasterize layer. I did  it, I redrw the whole thing in AI. Photoshop is hard. its the most hard soft I have ever seen. I am grateful for yout time. Thank you so much.

PS is hard for drawing vector shapes because it's a photo editing application. In this particular case PS is the hammer, Illustrator is the screwdriver.

lol. true.  I am thinking same.
